# Chat events messed up

Tags: bug, chat

I visited [chat.stackexchange.com](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms) and saw this:

[image: pic]

Why are events that happened 17 minutes ago in the ***upcoming*** events section?

Comment: @James Past event's aren't upcoming events.

Comment: Ok, I can see one has a future time. So perhaps the past time one has just begun and they just leave "recent" ones there - i.e. started within an hour ago. in which case you are right and it should perhaps be added to a "recently started" list.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think I see the problem here.

The thing is, the first site you see has an event **in** 13 hours:
[image]

The ***conference*** was opened 17 minutes ago, but the actual chat will be opened in 13 hours or so. But I do agree that the times are a little messed up.